# Torsion freeness of direct image of structure sheaf?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, singularity-theory

I have the following question.

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a surjective projective morphism between smooth projective varieties.
I learned that if $\dim Y=1$, then $R^if_*\mathcal O_X$ is torsion free $\forall i\geq0$.
I think smoothness of $X,Y$ is important here, and I wonder what about the condition $dim Y=1$?

***Q1***  Is it still true that $R^if_*\mathcal O$ is torsion free $\forall i\geq0$ when $\dim Y>1$? If false, what's a natural counter example? (To show how dimension of $Y$ matters).

Comment: As your questions stand, the answer is no for obvious reasons: just take for $f$ a closed immersion. You probably want $f$ surjective, $X$ connected, ...?

Comment: @abx Thanks.Yes I need $f$ surjective.

Comment: Q1: Take a normal surface $Y'$ with non-rational singularity. Let $g:X \to Y'$ be a resolution, and let $f:X \to Y = \mathbf{P}^2$ be the composition of $g$ with a finite map $Y' \to \mathbf{P}^2$. Then $R^1 f_* \mathcal{O}_X \neq 0$ and is supported at finitely many points.

Comment: @Anonymous Nice example, thanks!

Comment: If you strengthen your smoothness conditions, then it is true. Assume that $f$ is is smooth over $U=Y-B$ the complement of a snc divisor. Then $Rf_*\omega _X=\sum R^if_*\omega _X[-i]$ and each $R^if_*\omega _X$ and $R^if_*\mathcal O _X$ is locally free (Koll\'ar's Higher Direct Images II Thm 2.6). Note that the $R^if_*\omega _X$ are always torsion free.

Comment: @Hacon. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: In addition to @Hacon's comment, in [loc. cit. \S 3] Koll\'ar has also pinpointed the torsion free and the torsion part of $R^if_*\mathcal{O}_X$. The torsion free part is the dual of $R^{n-i}f_*\omega_X$ and hence is also reflexive.